# Finding the equation of the tangent (in slope-intercept form) at a particular point?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

One of the practice problems in my Calculus book is as follows: **The graph of y=$8/(x^2-4)$ is called the *Witch of Agnesi***.

**(a) Find y'**

**d/dx (u/v) = (v  du/dx - u  dv/dx)/($v^2$)**
**$=((x^2+4)(0)-(8)(2x))/((x^2+4)^2)$**
**$=(-16x)/((x^2+4)^2)$**

Assuming I've gotten **(a)** correct, I then am asked **(b) Find the equation of the tangent (in slope-intercept form) at the point (2,1)**.

Can anyone help me get rolling on this one?

Comment: one thing thats missing is the derivation of the equation $d/dx (u/v) = (v  du/dx - u  dv/dx)/v^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Undefined. Using your equation given and plugging $x=2$ gives $\frac80$ or undefined. The proper equation for the witch of agnesi is $\frac8{x^2+4}$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method to get you rolling:

The derivative of $f(x)$ is the slope of the tangent line at the point $(x, f(x))$. You already found the derivative to be $-\frac{16x}{(x^2+4)^2}$, so this is the slope of the tangent line at any point $(x, f(x))$.

To find the equation of the tangent line at $(2, 1)$, you first need to find the slope of the tangent line at $(2, 1)$, let's call it $m$. After you find $m$, you then plug $m$ and the point $(2, 1)$ into the point-slope formula and solve for $y$
$$ y - y_1 = m(x - x_1).$$

Comment: Ok, but how do I find $m$ to proceed?

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic To find $m$, you have to evaluate the derivative when $x$ is $2$ (plug $2$ in for $x$). This will give you the slope of the tangent line at $x=2$.

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic Feel free to accept my answer as the final answer by clicking the check mark under next to the voting arrows. Thanks!

Comment: I do not know how you picked it.[correct equation][1]  y= f(x) is in Mathworld
  [1]: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WitchofAgnesi.html Negative sign in denominator is incorrect. You may be barking the wrong tree, but no harm, procedure is clear from others' responses.